# How to show alert dialog once per app launch

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am creating an application that show alert dialog on launch of main activity of application but if i return to main activity from another activity then alert dialog is visible again. I want that alert dialog shown once at a app launch, how to do it ?

```
 if(isFirstRun) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You need to have Mobile data or Wifi to access all features.");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    isFirstRun = false;
```

**Working Code:-**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    boolean isFirstRun = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("IS_FIRST_RUN", true);

    if(isFirstRun == true) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You need to have Mobile data or Wifi to access all features.");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

        // Update
        editor.putBoolean("IS_FIRST_RUN", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

**Override onDestroy method:-**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    // Update
    editor.putBoolean("IS_FIRST_RUN", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you attempted?

Comment: @PrerakSola added code which i am using right now but not working

Comment: Why not just set a tag in your shared preferences? The first time the dialog is shown, set that value to true then next time you come back, check if it is false then show, otherwise, hide.

Comment: @Eenvincible can you give an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store the value of `isFirstRun` permanently for later use.

**Add below lines of code in your `MainActivity`, `onCreate()` method:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

boolean isFirstRun = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("IS_FIRST_RUN", false);

if(isFirstRun) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("You need to have Mobile data or Wifi to access all features.");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();

    // Update
    editor.putBoolean("IS_FIRST_RUN", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Reset `IS_FIRST_RUN` to your Activity `onDestroy()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    // Update
    editor.putBoolean("IS_FIRST_RUN", false);
    editor.commit();
}
```

**OR,** you can create a `class` extending from `Application` class and add above reset operations inside its `onDestroy()` method.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Check my updated answer. Use SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Yeah its working sir, but it show alert dialog only on the first launch of application. But my problem is that when i am using mine code that is in question it show alert dialog on every launch but when i am navigate from second activity to main activity alert dialog visible again. And i dont want that.

Comment: Ohh my mistake. Check my updated answer. You have to rest value when activity destroyed

Comment: Yeah now perfectly working, but i have to do some changes in code that is replacing **true** from **false**

Comment: Change as per your needs. Please remove the downvote if my answer seems usefule

Comment: Thats not mine sir, i cant vote till 15 level right now i am on 8.

Comment: Ohh i see. May be someone did this without knowing the context. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Fire it off from the application class. Try something like this

```
MyApplication extends Application {
    override public void onCreate() {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 // Show your dialog
            }  
        });
    }
}
```

Just a heads up, I just drafted this, will likely take some modification but it's the general gist.

Comment: its working but when i pressing home button of third activity from tool bar it take me to main activity and alert dialog visible again.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);  -- i am using this code onClick event of home button

Comment: This isn't in the activity context. This is the application context. Application onCreate() is only called on app startup. If the view gets added to the backstack (a dialog should not, but perhaps I am mistaken), you may be able to back into it and see again. If you perform this on the Activity onCreate, every time the activity is destroyed and displayed again, you will see the dialog

Comment: Another possibility is to implement a "splash screen" with the information of the dialog then, when the user navigates into the app, remove it from the backstack. I would highly recommend against a flag and use the lifecycle of the application instead.

Comment: Also the reason it's showing it again is because it sounds like  you're directing it to a new instance of the MainActivity and your flag is false again. Activities are not static.

Comment: Is there another method for activity transition ?

Comment: Try to use Shared Preferences check my answer , it's easy

Comment: Remember , that example needs to capture timing etc, it resembles splash screen . But **sharedprefence**  its just a matter of storing values , and you check them to perform any task. simple logic

Comment: Shared preferences are meant for user settings. While this will work, it's using the wrong tools for the job. With Android/ App development in general, I would recommend getting into the habit of capturing lifecycle.

Answer (score -1):

Try making isFirstRun static. This makes the variable a class variable, rather than an instance variable.

Defined here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293478/what-are-the-differences-between-class-variables-and-instance-variables-in-java

So, once you change this variable to false, it will stay false until the application is closed fully and then opened again. Ie, it will remain false when you come back from another application.

```
MyApplication extends Application { 

private static isFirstRun = true;

@override 
public void onCreate() {
    if(isFirstRun) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You need to have Mobile data or Wifi to access all features.");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    isFirstRun = false;
}

}
```

Comment: its working but again a problem is that when i am click on home button present on toolbar of third activity it take to main activity and alert dialog visible again.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);startActivity(intent); -- i am using this code on onClick method of home button

Answer (score -1):

Use `sharedpreference` on that issue , it will be more simpler,

Below is how you can beat that :

**First and foremost first Initialize sharedPreference in your App in the  `onCreate` Method :**

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_RUN, true);
    editor.commit();
```

and don't forget to declare this string also :

```
private static final String IS_FIRST_RUN = "IsFirstRun";
```

So since  `isFirstRun` our Method we have to put in some logic of shared preference and we check if `isFirstRun == True`  we show the dialog or else do something.

```
// Get isFirstRun State here 
    public boolean isFirstRun(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_RUN, true);
    }
```

Then you bring your code and say :

```
     if(isFirstRun) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("You need to have Mobile data or Wifi to access all features.");
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();

     SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_RUN, false);
       editor.commit();
            }

    else {
    // do something 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I would do it is to implement a unique Activity that only shows the AlertDialog and has a transparent theme. You can launch your existing activity as an intent once the AlertDialog is confirmed or cancelled. Or add a dismiss listener perhaps.

Bottom line is if the dialog does not feature as a routine part of MainActivity is should not form part of its design. Separate out the responsibilities.

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.transparent);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);

alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
alertDialog.setMessage("You need to have Mobile data or Wifi to access all features.");
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent i = new Intent( DialogActivity.this, MainActivity.class );
        startActivity(i);
        DialogActivity.this.finish();
    }

}); }
```

Make sure you set the Activity you want (the DialogActivity) as the launcher.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```